# Silverlight Unit Testing with Visual Studio Express

Tags: c#, silverlight, unit-testing, nunit, visual-studio-express

I *need* unit testing for my Silverlight application. I've separated out a DLL that has just core model classes, which  make sense to test.

Problem is, I'm on a Visual Studio Express stack. What are my options for unit testing?

I've seen:

1. [ScottGu's framework](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlightut) (don't seem to work for me)
2. [Jamie's Silverlight NUnit port](http://weblogs.asp.net/nunitaddin/archive/2008/05/01/silverlight-nunit-projects.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage) (doesn't work with Express)
3. [AgUnit](http://agunit.codeplex.com/) (I don't have JetBrains ReSharper)
4. NUnit 3.0 (doesn't exist yet)

What viable options do I have at this point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Jeff Wilcox's framework (it's the same one that you referenced up above as Scott Gu's), with some success.  It's not precisely elegant, but it ends up doing what I need it to do.  It's what the Silverlight team uses internally, so it should presumably cover most of what needs to be covered.  And since it's just executing in the browser, there's nothing in it that should keep it from working correctly with Express.

Do make sure you get the right version, i.e., you want the DLLs that come with the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/43528) up on Codeplex.  At one point, I'd ended up with an older version, and many of my problems went away once I got the most recent bits.

If you're having trouble getting it to work correctly, perhaps you could post your problem as a separate question.  I know that Jeff Wilcox hangs out here on occasion, and has answered some of my questions about it before.

Comment: I'll check it out and try it again. The problem is that I'm not using a typical Silverlight app; I'm developing using the FlatRedBall engine. I guess I'll see how it works out.

Comment: I tried this and I was very, very pleasantly surprised. Tutorial is here: http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2008/03/silverlight2-unit-testing/#option2